# When there is no option to kill some operation (who start in new thread) - what ere my options to do that?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using in my application with `Pcapdotnet` DLL's to determine my `Network Adapter` traffic rate via `Chart Control Graph`.

After form load the application start to listening to its adapter and show the statistics:

This is my `Combobox` selected adapter changed event:

```
MyObject obj;

private void comboBoxAdapter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    selectedAdapter = cmb.SelectedItem as NetworkAdapter;
    if (obj!= null)
        StopStatistics();
    StartStatistics();
}
```

After the application load the selected adapter who taken start to run the statistics:

```
private void StartStatistics()
{
    ThreadStart ts = delegate { obj.OpenAdapterForStatistics(selectedAdapter.PacketDevice); };
    Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

And i am show the statistics via timer:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (seriesBps.Points.Count() > 300)
        seriesBps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    seriesBps.Points.Add(obj.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

Now when i am change the adapter via my `Combobox` and want to listening different adapter i want firat to stop the statistics but because there is no Stop method i have left 2 option to do that:

1. `Kill my object` (called obj in this examples) to become `null`
2. `Thread.Abort()`

   private void StopStatistics()
      {
          timerChart.Stop();
          obj = null;
      }

So my question is which option is batter ?

Comment: Any reasons for not using Tasks which support cancellation? See [MSDN: Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What the different between Task.Cancel vs Thread.Abort vs MyObject = null ?